# SSH proxy, bad packet length

Tags: go, ssh, network-programming, goroutine

Implementing an ssh proxy in Go, errors out with bad packet length, these are the errors with ssh in debug mode:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Bad packet length 1231976033.
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to ::1 port 8080: message authentication code incorrect
```

Code:

```
func handleSSH(conn net.Conn, r *bufio.Reader, protocol string) {

    target, err := url.Parse("ssh://localhost:3333")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error parsing target", err)
        conn.Close()
        return
    }

    targetConn, err := net.Dial("tcp", target.Host)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error dialing SSH target:", err)
        conn.Close()
        return
    }

    defer targetConn.Close()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    go func() {
        _, err := io.Copy(targetConn, conn)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error copying data to target:", err)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    go func() {
        _, err := io.Copy(conn, targetConn)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error copying data from target:", err)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    conn.Close()
}

// EDIT

func connection(conn net.Conn) {

    r := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    protocol, err := r.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading first line", err)
        conn.Close()
        return
    }

if protocol[0:3] == "SSH" {
        handleSSH(conn, r, protocol)
    }
}

func main() {
   ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer ln.Close()

    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        go connection(conn)
    }
}
```

EDIT: added code for relevant information on how the connection is initiated and reproduce the error.

My best guess is the ssh negotiation process is being interrupted, and things goes out of sync.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt not sure what you mean but target.Host includes host:port https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#URL.Host

Comment: can you also paste the code at the call site of `handleSSH()` ? if possible: all the code from `listener.Accept()` to `handleSSH(conn, _, _)`

Comment: you are mentioning "ssh proxy", shouldn't `net.Dial(...)` be a `tls.Dial(...)` instead ? (that's a blind guess, and is the reason why I am asking about how you handle incoming connections to your proxy)

Comment: Please make your code a) complete to reproduce and b) reduce it to the bare minimum needed to show the problem. Right now it is a code fragment only which contains unused variables and which is missing relevant information about connection setup. Also, what is running on `localhost:3333` and have you checked that you can access it successfully directly with SSH?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich made an edit on how the connections are initiated. I checked and I can successfully ssh on localhost:3333 without going through the proxy port 8080

Comment: @LeGEC made an edit to show how the connections work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is reading the first line from the client and checks the kind of protocol in order to call the appropriate handler:

```
protocol, err := r.ReadString('\n')
...
if protocol[0:3] == "SSH" {
        handleSSH(conn, r, protocol)
    }
}
```

But the code fails to forward the already read bytes to the connected server. These bytes are in `protocol` and are given to `handleSSH`. But it fails to send these bytes to the connected server once the connection is established. Instead it only copies new data between client and server.

This means the server does not get the first line from the client. It therefore likely complains about a protocol error with something like `Invalid SSH identification string.` which gets forwarded to the client and misinterpreted as valid data from an SSH connection.

Comment: I guess you are referring to the r variable which holds the bytes read from the connection. I believe it is being passed as r in the handleSSH function if not correctly, please I would love to see a code sample to do that correctly.  I just complete the code because this is seemingly hard to debug.

Comment: @badman: I'm referring to `protocol`. See updated answer for clarificatin.